# 'activityInstanceId' field on execute request of a custom activity and where to find it in journey history?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, rest, custom-activity

I have a custom activity that uses `activityInstanceId` field from request as unique id for each request. I now need to somehow connect that id that I save on my side to contact for which activity was executed on SFMC. Unfortunately when I download the journey history through REST API, that field is nowhere to be found.
Is there anything I need to include in request for that field to be included in response or any other way to find connection between Contact Key and `activityInstanceId` for a particular activity execution?